# How to do vlookup without pandas using python script

Tags: python

I am having two csv files where I need a python code to do a vlookup that does match the values and takes only the needed column and creates a new csv file. I know it can be done with pandas but I need it to do this without pandas or any 3rd party tools.

```
INPUT 1 csv file

ID    NAME   SUBJECT 
1     Raj      CS
2     Allen    PS
3     Bradly   DP
4     Tim      FS

INPUT 2 csv file

ID     COUNTRY   TIME
2      USA       1:00
4      JAPAN    14:00
1      ENGLAND   5:00
3      CHINA     0.00

OUTPUT csv file

ID    NAME   SUBJECT  COUNTRY
1     Raj      CS     ENGLAND
2     Allen    PS       USA
3     Bradly   DP      CHINA
4     Tim      FS      JAPAN
```

Comment: You don't want `'TIME'` in in the output file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input1='.\file1.csv'
input2='.\file2.csv'


with open(input1,'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as inuputlist:
    with open(input2, "r",encoding='utf-8-sig') as inputlist1:
        with open('.\output.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as output:

            reader = csv.reader(inputlist)
            reader2 = csv.reader(inputlist1)
       
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            dict1 = {}
           
        
            for xl in reader2:
                dict1[xl[0]] = xl[1]

            for i in reader:
                if i[2] in dict1:                    
                 i.append(dict1[i[2]])
                 writer.writerow(i)
                else:
                 i.append("N/A")
                 writer.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a more efficient way to do it, but basically create a nested dictionary (using the `ID` as the key) with the other column names and their values under the `ID` key. Then when you iterate through each file, it'll update the dictionary on the `ID` key.

Finally put them together into a list and write to file:

```
input_files = ['C:/test/input_1.csv', 'C:/test/input_2.csv']
lookup_column_name = 'ID'

output_dict = {}
for file in input_files:
    file = open(file, 'r')
    header = {}
    
    # Read each line in the csv
    for idx, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        # If it's the first line, store as the header 
        if idx == 0:
            header = line.split(',')
            
            # Get the index value of the lookup column from the list of headers
            header_dict = {idx:x.strip() for idx, x in enumerate(header)}
            lookup_column_idx = dict((v,k) for k,v in header_dict.items())[lookup_column_name]
            continue

        line_split = line.split(',')
        
        # Initialize the dictionary by look up column
        if line_split[lookup_column_idx] not in output_dict.keys():
            output_dict[line_split[lookup_column_idx]] = {}
        
        # If not the lookup column, then add the other column and data to the dictionary
        for idx, value in enumerate(line_split):
            if idx != lookup_column_idx:
                output_dict[line_split[lookup_column_idx]].update({header_dict[idx]:value})

# Create a list of the rows that will be written to file under the correct columns            
rows = []            
for k, v in output_dict.items():
    header = [lookup_column_name] + list(v.keys())

    row = [k] + [output_dict[k][x].strip() for x in header if x != lookup_column_name]  
    row = ','.join(row) + '\n'
    rows.append(row)       

# Final list of rows, begining with the header
output_lines = [','.join(header) + '\n'] + rows
            
    
# writing to file
output = open('C:/test/output.csv', 'w')
output.writelines(output_lines)
output.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works like a charm but I've 1 more problem the Id in the input file 1 is in index 3 column and the input file Id is in index 1 how can match it with input file 1.

Comment: So you’re saying the output needs to match where ID is in file 1?

Comment: Yeah exactly , that would be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without pandas (and assuming you know the structure of your data + it fits in memory), you can iterate through the csv file and store the results in a dictionary, where you fill the entries where the ID maps to the other information that you want to keep.

You can do this for both csv files and join them manually afterwards by iterating over the keys of the dictionary.